# Django no carga mis archivos estáticos ni los archivos de la carpeta media con DigitalOcean

Tags: python, django, digitalocean

No carga mis archivos estáticos ni media de Django con DigitalOcean (aunque cuando corro con runserver todo corre normal). ¿Qué es lo que falla y cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Éste es mi código:
settings.py

```
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*',]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../imc-static/')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../imc-media/')
```

ubicación de mis archivos en digital ocean

```
root@django-512mb-nyc1-01:/home/django/imc# ls
db.sqlite3  imc  manage.py  public  requirements.txt  templates  webimc


root@django-512mb-nyc1-01:/home/django# ls
django_project  imc  imc-media  imc-static
```

Mi configuración para /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/django

```
upstream app_server {
    server 127.0.0.1:9000 fail_timeout=0;
}
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;

    client_max_body_size 4G;
    server_name _;

    keepalive_timeout 5;

    # Your Django project's media files - amend as required
    location /media  {
        alias /home/django/imc-media;
    }

    # your Django project's static files - amend as required
    location /static {
        alias /home/django/imc-static;
    }

    # Proxy the static assests for the Django Admin panel
    location /static/admin {
       alias /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://app_server;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Puede que sean varios errores:

1. Confirma mediante los log de `nginx`, que esté buscando los estáticos en el lugar que corresponde.
2. Verifica que `nginx` tenga permisos de lectura.
3. Puedes agregar un parte de log `nginx` para visualizarlo.